# for loop we use any local variable, what if we use any number present in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

In the for-loop we use any local variable, what if we use any number in a list? It turns out that for the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
b = []
for a[-1] in a:
    b.append(a[-1])
print(b)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

What did this code do? Is it legal in python?

Comment: *What will be the output?* why not run the code and check?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what the above does (consistent with [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)) is equivalent to:

```py
for ii in range(len(a)): 
    a[-1] = a[ii]
    b.append(a[-1])

print(b)
```

i.e. each item is in turn assigned to the last item in the array. In particular python accepts a general assignment target and not only an identifier for the iteration.